# re-configuring a worklight application with analytics

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-analytics

After redeploying a worklight application, some configuration for analytics got lost and I'm trying to configure worklight with analytics again.
The dashboard shows "No data available" for time after the deployment although there are old records displayed for the time before the deployment of the application. So the db was not affected.

I set the `wl.analytics.logs.forward` property to "true" in `worklight.properties`;
also I set the `wl.analytics.url` of the db to be something like:

```
https://myserver:port/analytics/data
```

The dashboard is on

```
https://myserver:port/analytics/console
```

That is the URL for the analytics server.

Although if I put the db URL in a browser I get something like:

> Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /data

Checked `SystemOut.log` and `SystemErr.log` (WAS logs) and I did not see errors there.

Does anybody know which is the XML I need to check in order to validate the configuration is OK for analytics? How could I troubleshoot this problem? Are there other logs I could check?

Comment: When you set "wl.analytics.url", is "myserver" (in your above example) the Worklight Server, or the Analytics server?  Have you looked at the logs from the analytics server?  When you say "checked the SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log in the server", do you mean the Worklight Server or the Analytics server?  Can you edit your question to clarify?  The info in the question is a little ambiguous right now.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify, i'll check the logs for the analytics server.

Comment: so i figured out one thing, i noticed that there are 2 wars inside IMF Operational Analytics.ear, one that stands for analytics and another for analytics-service, i changed the wl.analytics.url  to be analytics-service and i don't get a 404 error, i guess that is the correct url to use, however, i'm still seing "No data available" in the console

Comment: This may sound like a silly question ... but, you state that you are using a Worklight 6.2 server  Are you sure you're using 6.2 Analytics?  Analytics in 6.2 was packaged as a single WAR file (not an EAR file), and was not called "IMF Operational Analytics".  It sounds like you are using Operational Analytics from perhaps MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 or 7.1.

Comment: See this documentation for information on installing and configuring 6.2 analytics:  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_installation.html

Comment: Yes, we had already working IBM Mobile First Platform Operational Analytics with Mobile First Platform 6.3    Sorry for that mistake. Thank you i'll take a look at that documentation

Comment: @puki, any news after reading the correct documentation?

Comment: @IdanAdar keep seeing "No Data Available" 
i have 
-MFP 6.3
-all the apps deployed in Websphere, no separate servers. 
-redeployed worklight-analytics.war and worklight-analytics-service.war, didn't change any settings on them
-on the app i want to get the statics from, configured the environment entries like this

reports.exportRawData=true
wl.analytics.logs.forward=true
wl.analytics.url=https://myserver:port/worklight-analytics-service/data
wl.analytics.queues=10
wl.analytics.queue.size=20

Comment: Maybe you should open a PMR instead.

Comment: @puki was your question answered below?

Answer (score 1):

In the list of environment variables you gave I do not see any for username and password. Try to set:

`wl.analytics.password=admin`

`wl.analytics.username=admin`

It would be useful to see a wireshark trace, maybe you are not getting `403s`. The Analytics data uploader generally has a small bit of protections and you have the option to keep or remove it.

@patbarron is correct about the multiple WAR files though. You need to send your analytics data to the `/analytics-service` context. The WAR `analytics-service` is the WAR that handles all the data processing, querying, etc. The other WAR `analytics` just handles the console UI.

When testing it might be beneficial to lower the 
`wl.analytics.queue` and `wl.analytics.queue.size`, those values are for collecting data on the MobileFirst runtime server. Data is collected at the runtime server then sent to the analytics server. The larger these values are generally, the longer it will take to send. There are good to set for production